# Is there a standard UX icon for "select all children"

Tags: icons, controls, tree

I use a tree viewer **outline**  control to manage the data in my application.

Some folders in the outline may contain many 10s of child items.  For some operations a user will wish to select all of the child items in a folder.  They currently do this using shift-select.

But, for very long lists, this is cumbersome.  So, I wish to add a **Select all children** command to the toolbar (and right-click menu).

Is there a UX precedent for such a control?

I've done some googling, and found this:

[image: select all icon]

This is nice enough, but I haven't seen it before.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: What icon are you using for *Select*? *Select All Children* should be consistent with it.

Comment: Why are you using only an icon instead of the traditional "select all" checkbox?

Comment: Whatever icon you decide on, keep in mind that users probably won't understand what it means, so [you'll need to add a text label](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/).

Comment: A flute would be the best one. But, you would have to pay the piper.

Answer (score 3):

Material design suggest has as "Select All", the following.

[image: select all]

https://material.io/icons/

Please ask your users if they understand this icon before using it.

The most common practice is to use the same icon as you use for selecting individually, something like the following:

[image: select-all]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating a new icon and increasing the visual complexity of the application, why not use a checkbox instead? Selecting a parent checkbox could select all child items. No icons required. Instead use commonly known form elements.

Comment: Thanks @Hynes, but selecting the parent has its own meaning. Selecting an children is a share operation.